# C# httprequest headers wiht a colon .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, http-headers, httprequest

When inspecting a third party api using chrome browser's F12 tool I found there are several interesting headers listed:

```
:authority:m.somedomain.com
:method:GET
:path:/api/somevalues
:scheme:https
```

Along with some headers I'm familiar with, such as accept, accept-encoding, etc.

I'm using .Net 4.0 to make http/https requests. When trying to add these headers starting with a colon, an error is thrown on the first item:

```
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(":authority", "m.somedomain.com");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(":method", "get");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(":path", sPath);
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(":scheme", "https");
```

Error message:

> Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters.

After some searching I found article talking about http/2. However in .NET 4.0 there are only http/1.0 and http/1.1 available.

Does that mean I need to upgrade to newer .NET version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly. http/2 is supported from .NET version 4.6.2.

Click on the Project tab and select *properties* at the bottom. And then change your .NET version to 4.6.2.

Also I am 99.9% sure that you shouldn't include semi colon in your headers.

Further:

```
httpRequest.Headers.Add(":method", "get");
```

The request-method should not be defined in the header. Do it like so.

```
httpRequest.Method = "GET";
```

The scheme is usually indicated by the prefix of your url. ie:

```
string webAddr = "https://www.google.com/";
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
```